# ndk-build platinum-jni failed: arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -laxTls

Tags: android, android-ndk

To build the **`JNI`** shared library, you will need to have installed the Android NDK and set up the proper environment variables such as **`ANDROID_NDK_ROOT`**.

cd /Platinum
scons target=arm-android-linux build_config=Release

cd /Platinum/Source/Platform/Android/modules/platinum/jni
ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=0

import eclipse Android .project located @ /Platinum/Source/Platform/Android/modules/platinum/
This will create the jar file @ /Platinum/Source/Platform/Android/modules/platinum/bin/platinum.jar

The readme is above of building the platinum with ndk-build.
First step, command: "`scons target=arm-android-linux build_config=Release`", already succeeded. 
Second step, command: "`ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=0`", failed. The failed log is below.

```
wingyip@ubuntu:~/Desktop/PlatinumKit-1-0-3-0_a71192_66de97/Platinum/Source/Platform/Android/module/platinum/jni$ ndk-buildStaticLibrary  : libstdc++.aSharedLibrary  : libplatinum-jni.so/home/wingyip/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -laxTls/home/wingyip/android-ndk-r8c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: /home/wingyip/Desktop/PlatinumKit-1-0-3-0_a71192_66de97/Platinum/Source/Platform/Android/module/platinum/jni/../../../../../../Build/Targets/arm-android-linux/Release/libNeptune.a(NptTls.o): in function NPT_TlsContext::~NPT_TlsContext():NptTls.cpp(.text._ZN14NPT_TlsContextD1Ev+0x18): error: undefined reference to 'ssl_ctx_free'
```

System: ubuntu
NDK version: android-ndk-r8c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this problem too. It's just a typo, open Android.mk then change
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -laxTls
to:
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -laxTLS
You can see the lib's name is libaxTLS.a.